# How to run a subquery when inserting into a table in EFCore

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an `orderid integer` column in a `Postgres` table called `Orders` and it's not the primary key. And there's a logic to automatically increment it considering the max value of the `orderid` and adding 1 to it.

One solution to this is creating a function in the database layer and set it as the default value to this column. But since that couples us to the database layer, we are thinking of something that's related to `EF`. We can't pass a `SQL` as the default value to `orderid` because `postgres` gives an error. We can also make it an auto-increment value but we don't wanna do that because the logic could change.

What we want is a way to run this subquery and automatically generate the value to `orderid`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume what you want to achieve here is to maintain a separate non-primary key, auto-incremented unique id which is number. You can this by using a sequence.

1) Create the sequence via fluent API

2) Set the column to use the next value from the sequence

3) Make sure to create and run migrations before testing.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasSequence<int>("OrderNumbers")
                .StartsAt(1000)
                .IncrementsBy(1);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
                .Property(o => o.OrderNo)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("nextval('\"OrderNumbers\"')");
}
```